# Chat Application with Firebase using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

In my App, Activity.kt With attached with Adapter.kt and I'm work using RecyclerView in kotlin. In that Adapter.kt in the adapter member onBindViewHolder data parce in AnotherActivity.kt code. But, here problem is that there are no connection between two Activities (Activity.kt and AnotherActivity.kt). So, My problem is that how to the parce data between two activity without using Intent???

**Title: Adapter.kt**

```
class ChatAdapter (val chatList: ArrayList<ChatMessage>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ChatAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(p0.context).inflate(R.layout.chat_sort, p0, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return chatList.size
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: ChatAdapter.ViewHolder, p1: Int) {
        val chat: ChatMessage = chatList[p1]
            p0.msg.text = chat.msgText /// Problem with this data is send in AnotherActivity.kt code
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val msg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_msg_from_user) as TextView
}
```

There are not gone or start or launch AnotherActivity.kt . Only transfer data in the Adapter.kt. to AnotherActivity.kt

Comment: you should be able to do that with passing instances of activity google it

Answer (score 0):

You could create a application class having a getInfo() function in companion object function.

```
class MyApp : Application() {

    companion object {

        var info: String? = null

        fun getInfo(): String {
            return info
        }

        fun setInfo(info1: String) {
            info = info1 
        }
    }
}
```

You can simply get it using `MyApp.getInfo()`